# Error " No such filter '' " while merging videos FFMPEG

Tags: bash, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

Hey i newbie in FFMPEG and i'm trying to merge two videos and i get that error - No such filter: '' 
How i can fix that ? Here is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i videoplayback.mp4 videoplayback.mp4 -filter_complex 
"[0:v]trim=end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:d=1[intro];
[0:v]trim=start=1:end=123.39,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[main];
[0:v]trim=start=123.39,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=out:d=1[end];
[1:v]trim=end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:d=1[intro1];
[1:v]trim=start=1:end=123.39,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[main1];
[1:v]trim=start=123.39,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=out:d=1[end1];
[0:a][1:a][a];
[intro][main][end][intro1][main1][end1]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1,scale=480x360,setsar=16/9[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you meant to concat the audio in `[0:a][1:a][a];` but since no filter has been specified here, ffmpeg sees the three pads as inputs to a filter with a null string as its name.

Use `[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a];`

However, there are other errors in the command, and the whole command can be simplified to

`ffmpeg -i videoplayback.mp4 -i videoplayback.mp4 -filter_complex 
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=123.39:d=1[v0];
 [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=123.39:d=1[v1];
 [v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a];[v]scale=480x360,setsar=16/9[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`

Comment: Using your command i have error like that: Filter fade has an unconnected output